# Jquery insert value into input with php dynamic name

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I have a php generated form with fields retrieved from DB and I want to do in time calculations before save again in DB. Im retrieving all values from inputs and the sum is working, but Im not able to insert the sum result into a inputbox(it doesnt have to be necessarily a inputbox).
What im doing wrong?

Inside a php while I have the fields:

```
<td><input type="text" onkeyup="calculate(<?php echo($row["usr_id"]);?>)" class="valor_<?php echo($row["usr_id"]);?>" title="Valor Pago" style="font-size:18px; text-align:center;" value="<?php echo(formata_moeda($row["pedprod_valorpago"]));?>" name="<?php echo($row["usr_id"]);?>" id="<?php echo($row["prod_id"]);?>" /></td>
```

The TOTAL input is like this

```
<th><input type="text" class="totalpago_<?php echo($row["usr_id"]); ?>" name="totalpago_<?php echo($row["usr_id"]); ?>" id="totalpago_<?php echo($row["usr_id"]); ?>" value="<? echo(formata_moeda($total_valorpago_cestante)); ?>" disabled="disabled"></th>
```

And the javascript function

```js
function calculate(usrId) {
  var total = 0;
  var totalusr = 0;
  $("input.valor_"+usrId).each(function() {
  var price = parseFloat($(this).val().replace(',','.')); 
  totalusr += price; 
  //window.alert("Usuario: "+ usrId +" - Valor: "+ price);
   });
   
   $("input.totalpago_"+usrId).val(totalusr);
 window.alert($("input.totalpago_"+usrId).val());
}
```

This alerts are just to test proposes.

Comment: Why don't you just write jquery for keyup within input or a field, run the function. Because you can't hop between jquery and php like that

Comment: *"The TOTAL input is like this"* .... not in the browser it's not....only show html if you are trying to debug client side problem. The php is useless and nobody can copy your code to test it in javascript sandbox. Also need to show all relevant html as per [mcve]